# Gradle assembly debug failed not building app in VSCode

Tags: flutter, gradle

I tried running the default flutter app on VSCode; my device is successfully connected and I have enabled USB debugging, but when I run press f5 to debug and run the app the following error displays:

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on TECNO PR651E in debug mode...
    Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:220)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:289)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:265)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:372)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:203)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:189)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
    Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
    Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Check your internet connection and firewall settings on the device where you are compiling this code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to debug your project until you really want.
Debugging is used for testing your apps data flow or something.

**YOU MAY PRESS CTRL+F5 TO RUN WITHOUT DEBUGGING**

OR

Run > Run without debugging.